# Unit Testing. When to stop

Tags: unit-testing

I have been doing unit testing on my own projects for a little while now and wanted to get feedback on when to stop testing. Consider the following example.

```
public class Foo
{
    public object Bibble { get; private set; }

    public string Hooch { get; private set; }

    public string BibbleHooch { get { return string.Format("{0},{1}", Bibble, Hooch); } }

    public Foo(object bibble, string hooch)
    {
        if (bibble == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bibble");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hooch)) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("hooch");

        Bibble = bibble;
        Hooch = hooch;
    }
}
```

These are the following tests I can think of when the constructor is called.

- a null bibble throws
- a null hooch throws
- an empty hooch throws
- a valid bibble but null hooch throws
- a null bibble but valid hoow throws
- both bibble and hooch set to null throws
- a valid bibble and hooch do not throw
- a valid bibble and hooch mean Bibble and Hooch should not be null
- a valid bibble and hooch mean BibbleHooch should not be null
- a hooch x should be the same as Foo.Hooch
- a bibble y should be the same as Foo.Bibble
- a hooch of x and a bibble of y mean Foo.BibbleHooch should the the same as xy

Given that these are different permutations I would say they are all valid scenarios. Granted some duplication could be removed but the fact remains that there are a large number of tests needed to cover constructor creation. If I had SetBibble() / SetHooch methods I am getting into major duplication.

My question is: How much of the above would you test, how do you deal with tests that are permutations, when does the cost of writing the test exceed the value of the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you testing for interactions between unrelated parameters? You have named a lot of duplicate tests in your question. As I see it you have:

### Null tests

- `ArgumentNullException` test for null bibble
- `ArgumentNullException` test for null hooch
- `ArgumentNullException` test for empty hooch

### Property tests

- `Bibble` property set correctly by ctor
- `Hooch` property set correctly by ctor
- `BibbleHooch` property returns expected value

These 6 tests fully cover the entirety of possible scenarios in your class.

> If I had SetBibble() / SetHooch methods I am getting into major duplication.

Don't expose setters if it is not necessary. Prefer a minimal interface to your class - you will need fewer tests and the logic will be simpler.

Comment: When testing, how are you describing the happy path so. EG new Foo(null,"ValidString"); with "ValidString" being the happy path. Or maybe it might be better to ask how you are naming this test.

Comment: I would name that test `ThrowsNullArgumentExceptionOnNullBibble` (or whatever your equivalent naming convention is)... It's not a happy path!

Comment: I think it might be a case of over thinking my scenario's so. I was worried about making sure the happy path was explicitly mentioned but I think I will just not worry about it. As long as the tests work.

Comment: If you mean "how should I name the test to see whether the hooch property is set correctly?" then how about `HoochPropertySetCorrectlyFromCtor`...?

Comment: Ah, I see - no, you need not worry about mentioning what the "happy path" is (tests don't care!) instead focus on what actual behaviour is being tested, regardless of whether it is happy or exceptional

Answer (score 2):

I would test actual logic and not get carried away testing getters and setters. Usually getters and setters get covered in the course of testing the interactions between the objects. The only things in your example that I see as possibly need testing are that the IllegalArgumentExceptions get thrown, and that the formatting works. (Considering your properties allow the members to get reset to null, testing that the exception gets thrown doesn't have a lot of value.)

Unit tests are supposed to be primarily useful to the developer, they're not there to make management happy or satisfy code-coverage metrics (although there are plenty of places that get carried away with that kind of thing). I wouldn't spend time testing for different combinations of things that are not interrelated.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I put an upvote on you because I think I need to take this into account too. I think I might be over testing in some situations.